# Custom navigation bar hides by another navigation bar but it didn't show in swift storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I inserted a new ViewController and added a navigation bar, but as can be seen in the image below, the navigation bar is hidden. I think there is a navigation bar that exists already but it didn't show up in storyboard. How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Are you adding one view controller into another? Please check that first

Comment: @Dharmik no i am not adding view controller into another

Comment: Ok, some times, xcode behaves weirdly. So delete you viewController files, .m, .h and xib and create new one with new name and check. if not work, Please update your question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was the navigation bar is already exist in view controller but it doesn't show in storyboard. To solve this
**Click on the viewController in storyboard then on the right from Attributes Inspector change the type of Top Bar for example choose Translucent nav bar then it will appear**

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard select your Navigation Controller, turn off shows navigation bar[image]